# Как запустить сайт, написанный на flask без установленного python, vs code?

Tags: python, flask

Допустим, я хочу, чтобы друг открыл у себя мой сайт, я ему кидаю папку с html, css и python файлами, но у него нет ни visual studio, ни установленного python. Как это можно сделать? Я совсем новичок.

Comment: Установить python ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Запакуй в pyinstaller, py2exe или подобный упаковщик.

Answer (score 0):

есть много решении этого вопроса,
как выше написали, можно всякими упаковщиками, а можно еще:

1. Задеплоить проект на сервер - для вас будет сложновато
2. Если у вас статичный IP. то открыть порт через который запущен проект и дать другу свой IP и порт, следующим способом: IP:ПОРТ - тоже есть сложности, возможно на роутере придется открыть порт
3. Запустить проект локально (на вашем компьютере) и перебросить порт к ngrok

последнее самый быстрый способ, вот пример:
сначала скачать его https://ngrok.com/ потом запустить проект на фласке и запустить ngrok указав нужный порт

```
$ flask run
$ ngrok http 80
```

и в ответ должно запринтиться ссылка, которую и можете передать другу

ps. если каким-то образом ngrok недоступен у вас, то можно так же посмотреть в сторону http://localhost.run/